# Change LiveTile on Windows 8 app while running

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, windows-8, windows-runtime

I want to change the LiveTile of my Windows 8 app while it is runnig. So the user can configure something in the app and then I want to display a local stores image as LiveTile.

How can I realize this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a blog post with code samples on how I implemented live tiles, with links to other resources that helped me: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jennifer/archive/2012/11/20/real-world-live-tiles-working-with-live-tiles-in-windows-8-apps.aspx

Comment: Thanks for answer. How can I apply LiveTiles for both sizes (small and wide)?  Is it possible to get the information which tile size my app has?

Comment: No, it's not possible to get the information on which tile size the user has set your app to, so you always send both sizes in your live tile update, and the operating system will choose the right one to apply.  If you look at the final code that I posted near the end of the blog post, you will see that I first create a live tile update for the square size, then I create an update for the wide size, then I merge them, and send that merged version in the tileNotification.

Comment: Thanks. Your code works very well. One last question: You set an expiration date of the live tile. Is it possible to set the expiration to the next reboot of the system?

Comment: No, it's not possible to tie the expiration to an event (like the next reboot of the system); the expiration must be a DateTimeOffset.

Answer (score 0):

You use The TileUpdater.update method, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.notifications.tileupdater.update.aspx. Examples of this are in the App Tiles and badge sample, scenarios 2 and 3 (for images). You can find the sample at http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/App-tiles-and-badges-sample-5fc49148#content.